# Different append of n item to list and [0]*n in python?

Tags: python

I have two Code that is same
`Code1`

```
>>> a=[0]*60000000
```

`Code2`

```
>>> a=[]
>>> for i in range(0,60000000):
        a.append(0)
```

in My pc Time needed for `Code1` is 1s But for `Code2` is 480s !!
Why ? Waht is Different?

Comment: code1: is pure memy initialization; where as code2 bears 2 overhead list - courtesy **range()** and not to forget the **for** loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In what follows I'm assuming you're using Python 3; in Python 2 the story would be similar but we'd have to discuss the cost of memory allocation due to `range`.)

Your second program spends its time running *in Python bytecode*. Let's disassemble it using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('a=[]\nfor i in range(0,60000000):\n a.append(0)')
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0 
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a) 

  2           6 SETUP_LOOP              36 (to 45) 
              9 LOAD_NAME                1 (range) 
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (0) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (60000000) 
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             21 GET_ITER             
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                19 (to 44) 
             25 STORE_NAME               2 (i) 

  3          28 LOAD_NAME                0 (a) 
             31 LOAD_ATTR                3 (append) 
             34 LOAD_CONST               0 (0) 
             37 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             40 POP_TOP              
             41 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22 
        >>   44 POP_BLOCK            
        >>   45 LOAD_CONST               2 (None) 
             48 RETURN_VALUE
```

The loop runs from bytes 22 to 41, and each time round the loop, Python has to decode and execute seven byte code instructions, and call a function too (the function being `a.append`). That's 420 million byte code instructions and 60 million function calls.

Whereas your first program spends its time running *in native code*:

```
>>> dis.dis('a = [0] * 60000000')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0) 
              3 BUILD_LIST               1 
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (60000000) 
              9 BINARY_MULTIPLY      
             10 STORE_NAME               0 (a) 
             13 LOAD_CONST               2 (None) 
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that not only is there no loop, there are no function calls. All the work happens "under the hood" inside the `BINARY_MULTIPLY` instruction, which dispatches to [`list_multiply` in `listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ae9b74c2b357/Objects/listobject.c#l509), and since the list `[0]` contains just one element, the result is constructed in this tight loop at lines 529–536:

```c
if (Py_SIZE(a) == 1) {
    elem = a->ob_item[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        items[i] = elem;
        Py_INCREF(elem);
    }
    return (PyObject *) np;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` in Python 2.7 creates a list itself, and not an iterator. Therefore, you do double the work in `Code2`. That means, you first create a list of 6000000 items, and then iterate over it. `Code1` does not need that intermediate step.

> This [range] is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions

Soure: [Range Python 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Compare that to Python 3.x:

> Rather than being a function, range is actually an immutable sequence
>   type, as documented in Ranges and Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.

Source: [Range Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Try to use `xrange` instead of `range`, and test it again.

Comment: OK Thank you. But Why Time for Code2 != 2*Code1?!

Comment: Creating the list and using the **for** is much more expensive than the stuff you do in Code1, especially when you count in issues related to memory handling of your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you used `range` instead of `xrange`, there are two things that are going on:

1) The functions don't do the same thing, though they arrive at the same output.  Your `code1` means "60 million copies of `[0]` concatenated together".  That is not what `Code2` is doing, obviously- it has to call the `append` method of lists 60 million times.

2) Explicit loops in python are slow.  There is a loop in `Code1`, somewhere, but it occurs "at C speed" as opposed to, well, python speed.

```
def f():
    a = [0]*6000000

def g():
    a = []
    for i in xrange(6000000):
        a.append(0)

%timeit f()
10 loops, best of 3: 31 ms per loop

%timeit g()
1 loops, best of 3: 358 ms per loop
```

In a tight loop like this, the majority of the overhead is in the *loop itself* rather than the operations contained therein.  So a popular method to optimize tight loops is to drop them into a comprehension:

```
def h():
    [0 for _ in xrange(6000000)]

%timeit h()
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop
```

Note that again the two functions are not doing the same thing, which is why there is discrepancy between `f` and `h`.